# select * using Group By Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this tables

```
column1 column2 colum3 column4 colum5 column6

a       b       1      2        0     x
a       b       1      2        0     y
a       b       3      0        0     z
```

I want to group the same record

my sql code looks like this but it gives the same result (`select * from employee where column1 = 'a' and column2= 'b'`)

```
SELECT a.column1,a.column2,a.column3,a.column4,a.column5
FROM employee a,
    (SELECT column3, column4,column5
     FROM employee  
     WHERE column1 = 'a' and column2= 'b'
     GROUP BY column3 colum4 column5) b
WHERE a.column3 = b.column3,
and a.column4 = b.column4,
and a.column5 = b.column5,
```

the result should be like this:

```
column1 column2 colum3 column4 colum5 
a       b       1      2        0       
a       b       3      0        0
```

Comment: Did you try DISTINCT?

Comment: @forpas DISTINCT does not give the correct result

Comment: Did you try it? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed38d7746c3f344ddbdf485cabe4ce3e

Comment: On what basis you want the result, how do you define line no 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with window function `row_number()`, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69a3ce39e8278146bb9e223d475715c4).

```
select
  column1,
  column2, 
  colum3,
  column4,
  colum5
from
(
  select
    column1,
    column2, 
    colum3,
    column4,
    colum5,
    row_number() over (partition by column1, column2, colum3, column4, colum5 order by column1) as rnk
  from myTable
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
*---------------------------------------*
| COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUM3  COLUMN4 COLUM5|
*---------------------------------------*
|  a        b       1        2      0   |
|  a        b       3        0      0   |
*---------------------------------------*
```

Comment: @ErenDurmuş did you check the demo. It is giving the expected result then how you are getting different result.

Comment: @ErenDurmuş https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69a3ce39e8278146bb9e223d475715c4

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, a simple `distinct` on the first five columns would return the result that you expect:

```
select distinct column1, column2, column3, colum4, column5
from employee
```